# Issues setting up Doc merge from word to excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, merge, ms-word

I am an amateur coder very new to VBA with a little experience in C+

I was able to find code to execute a doc merge using macros in word but when I run it I receive these 2 errors.

The line:

`MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, _
        vbOKOnly, "Error"`

returns the following error in an Error dialog box:

5941: The requested member of the collection does not exist.

The line:

```
cnn.Close
```

returns the following error in a Microsoft Visual Basic dialog box:

Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set

Here is the code used

Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated

```
Sub TransferToExcel()
'Transfer a single record from the form fields to an Excel workbook.
  Dim doc As Document
  Dim strObligee As String
  Dim strJob As String
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
  'Get data.
  Set doc = ActiveDocument
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  strObligee = Chr(39) & doc.FormFields("txtObligee").Result & Chr(39)
  strJob = Chr(39) & doc.FormFields("txtJob").Result & Chr(39)
  'Define sql string used to insert each record in the destination workbook.
  'Don't omit the $ in the sheet identifier.
  strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$]" _
    & " (Obligee, Job)" _
    & " VALUES (" _
    & strObligee & ", " _
    & strJob _
    & ")"
  Debug.Print strSQL
  'Define connection string and open connection to destination workbook file.
  Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
  With cnn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Users\Ntrojan\Documents\word to excel project\fieldheaders.xlsx;" & _
      "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    .Open
    'Transfer data.
    .Execute strSQL
  End With
  Set doc = Nothing
  Set cnn = Nothing
  Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, _
    vbOKOnly, "Error"
  On Error GoTo 0
  On Error Resume Next
  cnn.Close
  Set doc = Nothing
  Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that you can use the [edit] link below your question to add additional information to it - trying to trouble-shoot from numerous comments is very difficult. Extraneous comments can then be deleted.

Comment: @NPettMHallmark `On Error Resume Next` basically ignores all errors - so when you hit that line, `cnn.Close` should not throw any kind of error. But like what Cindy said, you shouldn't even be able to *get* to that line, since that only occurs in your error handling routine..

Comment: As I said, we need to know what line of code is triggering the error handler. Use F8 to step through the code and you should see what the last line is before the message box. Or comment out the error handling completely so that you can use Debug to see the line. FWIW my best guess would be that you've misspelled a FormFields name...

Comment: I'm still not seeing which line triggers the display of the MsgBox... FWIW this is the problem - the cnn.close is a red herring - that's only happening because cnn is never initialized due to the error not running Set cnn... As I said, you've probably misspelled a FormField name...

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister, we got the code to work but it does not input into the correct cell. It is in the correct column but not in the correct row. It starts at row 10 when it should start at row 2. How do I manipulate the code so that it starts at row 2? Thanks

Comment: In that case, you should start a new question that specifically targets the new problem. No single person is an expert in all aspects of everything. And the way the site works (Q&A, not a "forum") changing topic in "mid-stream" is not good :-) But glad you've made progress!